# Update Java Applet label using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, runnable, marquee

I have the following Applet class:

```
public class Marquee extends Applet {
    Label label1 = new Label("Testing");

    public void pushUpdate( String text ) {
        System.out.println( "receiving: " + text );
        label1.setText( text );
        repaint();
    }

    public void init() {
        ScrollText_2 scrollObj = new ScrollText_2( "Applet test" );
        scrollObj.setApplet(this);
        add( label1 );
        scrollObj.run();
    }
}
```

The ScrollText2 class implements Runnable and has a scroll() method. Right now, all the scroll method does is return the String that the object contains. The run() method of this class looks like this:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        marquee.pushUpdate( scroll() );
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

The problem is that when I run the applet, if I call the .run() method, then the label on the marquee never displays.  I have tried repaint(), just label.setText(), updateUI(), and redraw() to try and get the applet to display the updates but it didn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: does "receiving:..." print out in the console? If it doesn't, the problem could be that you are putting the `Thread` to sleep before it can update the UI. Try removing `Thread.sleep(2000)` in that case.

Comment: Yes, the receiving println does print out, the UI just doesn't seem to update.

Comment: Did you try removing the `Thread.sleep` anyways?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) As alluded to via HFOE's question, use Swing in this millennium, as opposed to AWT. 3) There are simple ways to achieve this using a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that calls `repaint()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call `run()` of a Thread or Runnable. You call `start()` on the Thread or of a Thread that contains the Runnable. Also, you will need to take care to update the GUI components on the GUI's thread. For Swing that means using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(someRunnable)`, and I suspect it can be done similarly with AWT.

By the way, why use AWT and not Swing?

Comment: +1 for considering `invokeLater`. Multithreading can be downright devious.

Answer (score 3):

You are not creating a new `Thread` to run `scrollObj`. When you call `scrollObj.run()` in `Marquee.init()`, `scrollObj` hijacks your applet thread. This means that your main `Marquee` update loop, which includes `paint()`, is never reached. Invoking `repaint()` also does not guarantee that `paint()` is called. Thus, your `Marquee` is never painted.

Your code works fine when you replace `scrollObj.run();` with

```
new Thread(scrollObj).start();
```

Comment: After reading Hovercraft's answer, I realize that it would be more proper to call `EventQueue.invokeLater(scrollObj)` instead - this sets up your applet's GUI before `scrollObj` is started.

Comment: No, you're right. He should call `start()` on the thread that holds the Runnable above, but then inside of the code above, the original poster should place the `marquee.pushUpdate( scroll() );` call into a Runnable and then queue the Runnable on the event thread using `invokeLater(...)`. Up-voted and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

marquee example in applet for thread like moving something

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
/**<applet code="Marquee" height=768 width=1024></applet>*/
public class Marquee extends Applet implements Runnable {
  Color clr[] = { Color.red, Color.green, Color.cyan, Color.blue, Color.orange };
  int xx = 0;
  int x = 100;
  int a = 200;
  Thread t = new Thread(this);

  public void start() {
    t.start();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 28));
    xx++;
    if (xx == 3) {
      xx = 0;
    }
    g.setColor(clr[xx]);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, x, a);
    g.drawString("Vinay", x, 200);
    g.drawString("Mayur", a, 300);
    x += 1;
    a -= 1;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      System.out.println("sdd");
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
        repaint();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error:-->" + e);
    }
  }
}
```